# How to reorder modules in webpack bundle

Tags: webpack, module, gzip, deflate

Is there a way to change modules order inside the bundle?

It could help with better gzipping. Via the plugin API maybe? gzip uses deflate, and deflate likes it when repetitions are within 32Kb away from each other. And the closer the better.
Which could probably be achieved with some heuristics, or exhaustive search for small number of sortable units.

I made some experiments, with simply concatenating files from my codebase (1000+ js/css/glsl files) ordered with different strategies, and then feeding concatenated result to zopfli. Resulting sizes varied roughly from -4.8% to +10.6% depending on sorting strategy. (0 - being directory structure traversing order). And I think it could be improved a little further.

But it doesn't make much sense if reordering modules inside the bundle is not allowed. So, is there some way to do so?

Comment: _It could help with better gzipping._ Nowadays browsers support Brotli compression. In my experience React script bundles are ~19% smaller when compressed using Brotli compatively to gzip. It might be more beneficial to spend time on configuring webpack to use both compressions types and then let the clients choose.

Comment: Scanned through Brotli spec. It seems Brotli could still benefit from such reordering, because of variable length of its distance codes. Yet brotli is a much more complex format than deflate, and has other means of referencing subsequences that appeared before than jumping to a fixed distance. Therefore I'll need to experiment on it a little bit more to be sure.

Comment: I tried the same files with brotli. The best result -0.5%, the worst +1.4%. And yes, about 25% better than correspondent zopfli. Still worth it I think).